# What is semalt.semalt.com that shows up in Google Analytics under Referrals?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, sem, universal-analytics, semalt

How does it work? How does it drive traffic and referrals? When I go there, it wants me to sign up for something. Is it a scam? It is 10% of my traffic for the last week.

Comment: Yes it is. Check out this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72107/semalt-ignores-robots-txt-does-their-own-form-actually-do-what-they-promise/72111#72111

Comment: Moderator. While the question is not exactly the same, there is overlap in the two questions. I leave it up to you to decide if these are duplicate or not. It is a judgement call. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I wonder why it didn't show up in the list of related questions during typing it? According to that answer, it is a scam.

Comment: I sometimes find answers in that list and sometimes not. But you just got lucky in your timing that I happened to see your question and answer a similar question before. On stuff like this, I like to be as responsive as possible. I hate scams! We all work too hard for this kind of junk to happen.